# Customers have multiple account

Tags: if-statement, hive, conditional-statements, case

[image]We have a table that contains customer's accounts. One of these customers happens to have multiple accounts.

**Customer table:**
*(Format: customer_ID Name)*

- 101  Smith
- 102  Williams
- 103  Martin
- 104  Jack

**Account table**
*(Format: Account_ID, customer_ID,Account_Type)*

- Account_ID   customer_ID Account_Type
- 201  101 A1
- 202  101 B1
- 203  101 C1
- 301  102 B1
- 302  102 C1
- 401  103 A1
- 402  103 C1
- 501  104 B1

If one customer has multiple accounts, we select account_type base on this order: A1, C1, and B1

The result should be :

- customer_ID  Account_Type
- 101  A1
- 102  C1
- 103  A1
- 104  B1

I write the following query:
Select c.customer_ID, case
when Account_Type in ('A1','B1' 'C1' ) then A1
when Account_Type in (''B1' 'C1' ) then C1
else Account_Type 
End
From customer c
join account a
on a.customer_ID=c.customer_ID

How can I put the condition: one customer has multiple accounts in this query?

Thanks

Comment: How can I put the condition: one customer has multiple accounts in this query? - Please elaborate or share the desired output

Comment: The desired output will be: customer_ID  Account_Type
101 A1
102 C1
103 A1
104 B1

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution would be

SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT *, CASE AccountType WHEN 'A1' THEN 1 WHEN 'B1' THEN 3 WHEN 'C1' THEN 2 END As Rank1  FROM testAccount 
) A Order by CustomerID, Rank1

Comment: Hi Brijest, I do not get the result when running your query

Comment: Have you changed the tableName? it should give the result. Share sample data

Comment: The result list all customer account. My Desired result is just listed customer with the high order. If the customer_Id 101 have three accounts: 201 (A1), 202(B1) and 203(C1). I need to show 101 with A1

Comment: a.account_id  | a.customer_id  | a.account_type  | a.rank1  |
+---------------+----------------+-----------------+----------+--+
| 201           | 101            | A1              | 1        |
| 203           | 101            | C1              | 2        |
| 202           | 101            | B1              | 3        |

Comment: I only need 201 , 101, A1,